# How to use map units to define radius of point feature in styles in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

I have a point feature in a map which is in EPSG32723 (WGS84 - UTM zone 23s) and I need to style it as follows: A center point in red and a circle below it which has a particular size in meters.

I tried doing that in styles using map units for the size of the second but when I measured it using measure tool the circle had half (3 meters) of what it was supposed to be (6 meters).

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The **symbol size** in QGIS refers to the size of the bounding box, not the radius. So in the case of a simple circle marker, the size refers to the diameter, not the radius. The same goes for ellipse markers.

I think this might be because there are lots of types of symbol (circle, triangle, cross, SVG symbols), so treating circles differently would add complexity.

There is fairly recent addition (in 2.12, I think) called **Size Assistant**, which allows you to set the size using a radius instead. (You can see it in your screenshot, at the bottom of the menu).

Once you get the dialog up, set the **Scale Method** to **Radius**...

[image: size assistant dialog]

Comment: of course, seems so obvious now. thank you very much for the help, steven.